# My Haskell programme to convert Sets to Lists is getting an error

Tags: list, haskell, types, set

I am a beginner programmer and I have made a data type for my sets. I have then written a function to convert them to lists but I keep getting the following error message for the expression:

```
toList 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty
```

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Set a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)

When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num (Set a), Num [a]) => Set [a]
```

Here is my Code:

```
infixr 5 :-:
data Set a = Empty | a :-: (Set a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

toList :: Set a -> [a]
toList Empty = []
toList (x :-: xs) =  x : toList xs
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. This code doesn't mention `Num` at all, so it's not clear where your error is coming from.

Comment: I tried applying the function toList to the set 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty. I don't know if that helps?

Comment: Please post the exact text that you typed in GHCi

Comment: toList 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty

Comment: That gets parsed as `(toList 3) :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty`, so `4` becomes the `Set a` argument to `:-:`. Try `toList (3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `toList 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty` is parsed as `(toList 3) :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty`, but you actually wanted `toList (3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty)`. To make it work, you need to write the latter, or use `$`, like this: `toList $ 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty`.

Comment: Thankyou, that has worked perfectly. Is there anything I can change in my code to make the program run as intended?

Comment: Do you mean that you want `toList 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty` to do what you want without my changes? No, there's no way to do that.

Comment: That question is a bit like asking if it's possible to say "I like apples" in a way that means "I hate coffee"